# How to post to an API using aspnet 2.0

Tags: asp.net, rest, .net-2.0

A service a subscribed to uses an api and provided this sample php bellow.
I have an old aspnet script which i want to modify to do the same but as i am not a programmer and having hard time with it. i read about httpclient and various codes but non do exactly what i need. Can this be easily ported?  thanks /J

```
    $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client->post("https://api.domain.com/v3/accounts", [
    'headers' => [
            "Authorization" => "Bearer {token}",
            "Accept" => "application/json",
            "Content-Type" => "application/json",
        ],
    'json' => [
            "username" => "eius",
            "password" => "nemo",
        ],
]);
$body = $response->getBody();
print_r(json_decode((string) $body));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `url` and `token` to the correct values you need, minimal code example Console app:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var url = "https://postman-echo.com/post";
    var token = "super secret token";
    var httpWR = WebRequest.CreateHttp(url);
    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var result = string.Empty;

    httpWR.Accept = "application/json";
    httpWR.ContentType = "application/json";
    httpWR.Method = "POST";
    httpWR.Headers.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {token}");

    using (var sw = new StreamWriter(httpWR.GetRequestStream()))
    {
        string json = serializer.Serialize(new
        {
            username = "eius",
            password = "nemo"
        });
        sw.Write(json);
    }

    var response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWR.GetResponse();
    using (var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        result = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }

    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Comment: Thank a lot! i am making progress with this but can't seem to put it inside an IF Else statement. keep getting error for expected }.   Should i be able to but that code inside an IF else statement? thanks

Comment: @kattouf welcome to SO, if you have a new question for the next step then please open a new question, if this answer solved your original question then please accept it https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers